# Is there a way to create a tabbed picker in iOS? Or somehow combine numpad + picker inputs?

Tags: ios, uipickerview, numeric-keypad

I'm looking for a clean way to enable two interactions within one screen.

For example:

1) User clicks on "Add Activity" button

2) User enters a number of standard units (e.g., 10 meters), and then picks an associated activity from a list (e.g., picklist of: jog, run, walk, crawl)

All I can think of right now is creating two separate entry fields - one that calls up numpad, and another that calls up the picker. Is it possible to created a tabbed numpad so that the user completes numerical entry, then just hits 'Activity Type' above the numpad and the element switches to a picker?

Appreciate any inputs!

Answer (score 0):

Not with a stock keyboard. If all you need is a numpad, you ought to be able to implement a very reasonable keyboard out of a few buttons. Add a couple of "tab" buttons, and show/hide the appropriate view: keyboard or picker.